# Populate Gridview from Data Table

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I am attempting to populate a Gridview from a Data Table.  However, when I run the code, nothing at all is showing up in the Gridview.  Here is the code:

```
string serverIP = drpServer.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\\" + serverIP + "\\root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process");

        foreach (ManagementObject query in searcher.Get())
        {               
            var processName = query["Name"];
            var processID = query["IDProcess"];
            var cpuTime = query["PercentProcessorTime"];
            var memUsage = query["WorkingSet"];

            double newMemUsage = Convert.ToDouble(memUsage);

            newMemUsage = newMemUsage / 1024;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ProcessName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProcessID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("CPUTime", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("MemoryUsage", typeof(string));

            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["ProcessName"] = processName;
            row["ProcessID"] = processID;
            row["CPUTime"] = cpuTime;
            row["MemoryUsage"] = newMemUsage;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

I like the Management Object Searcher better than using Diagnostics.Process which is why I am going that route.

I have created the Bound Fields in my Gridview as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is your `foreach` wrapping the entire procedure? That will create an entire new `DataTable` each time you get a new query. I think you meant to do the following, which only wraps the add row piece:

```
string serverIP = drpServer.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"\\" + serverIP + "\\root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process");

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ProcessName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("ProcessID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("CPUTime", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("MemoryUsage", typeof(string));

foreach (ManagementObject query in searcher.Get())
{   
    var processName = query["Name"];
    var processID = query["IDProcess"];
    var cpuTime = query["PercentProcessorTime"];
    var memUsage = query["WorkingSet"];

    double newMemUsage = Convert.ToDouble(memUsage);

    newMemUsage = newMemUsage / 1024;

    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["ProcessName"] = processName;
    row["ProcessID"] = processID;
    row["CPUTime"] = cpuTime;
    row["MemoryUsage"] = newMemUsage;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didnt notice that.  I made the change and it looks to be populating now but all rows are blank.  I will debug and see if the values are even being written.

Comment: No problem. That may be an issue with your query itself. If you set a break point at `double newMemUsage` you should be able to see if you have any values for `processName`, etc. Then you can set another breakpoint at the end bracket of your `foreach` to see if `dt` contains any values in the result set (under Watch or Locals).

Comment: I through this in a console app so I could bypass the gridview and the data is being written to console.  There may be an issue with getting the right value from my drop down.  I will debug that and see.  Thank you for all of the help.

Comment: I created these columns in my aspx page but do I need to set the values to something?  Everything is working except the binding.

Comment: I hadn't defined the data fields.  Once I did that everything is populating.