# Convert JSON response from REST API into DataTable

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to convert a json response from REST API into a `DataTable`. The following is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data;

namespace RestDemo1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getEmployeeData();
        }

        public static void getEmployeeData()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://crmscf.vidyasystems.com/api/gen/items.php");
            var request = new RestRequest("items");
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            string vJ = "";

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string rawResponse = response.Content;
                DataTable tester = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rawResponse, (typeof(DataTable)));
            }
        }

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public int success { get; set; }
            public Item[] items { get; set; }

            public class Item
            {
                public string ItemID { get; set; }
                public string ItemName { get; set; }
                public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
                public string MRP { get; set; }
                public string Rate { get; set; }
                public string Unit { get; set; }
                public string Weight { get; set; }
                public string ItemGroup { get; set; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try get the data into a table format, I get error:

```
DataTable tester = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rawResponse, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

> Error message- Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

Comment: DEBUG! Set a breakpoint after `string rawResponse = response.Content;` Now check the json.

Comment: I am able to get the response. I am even able to deserialize it using `dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rawResponse)`

Comment: @SDS first convert it to array and then deserialize the array `string[] stringArray = new string[]{ someString };`

Comment: Can you please share with us a sample json?

Comment: The error says it all: `Expected StartArray, got StartObject` - the json is not an array as it should be.

Comment: I get this kind of raw response from [https://crmscf.vidyasystems.com/api/gen/items.php] -'{"success":1,"items":[{"ItemID":"13","ItemName":"Diamond (50 Kg PP)","ItemDesc":"","MRP":"0","Rate":"0","Unit":"","Weight":"50","ItemGroup":""},{"ItemID":"3","ItemName":"Diamond (59 Kg Jute)","ItemDesc":"","MRP":"0","Rate":"0","Unit":"","Weight":"59","ItemGroup":""},{"ItemID":"2","ItemName":"Diamond (59 Kg PP)","ItemDesc":"","MRP":"0","Rate":"0","Unit":"","Weight":"59","ItemGroup":""},{"ItemID":"12","ItemName":"Diamond (60 Kg PP)","ItemDesc":"","MRP":"0","Rate":"0","Unit":"","Weight":"60","ItemGroup":""}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is a `Rootobject` type, but not a `DataTable` type. Hence, you can't deserialize the `response.Content` to `DataTable` type.

What you need to do:

1. Deserialize `response.Content` to the `Rootobject` instance.
2. Extract the `items` (a list with `List<Rootobject.Item>` type) from the `Rootobject` instance.
3. Convert the `List<Rootobject.Item>` to `DataTable` via the extension method `IListExtensions.ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> list)`.

```cs
string rawResponse = response.Content;
                
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(rawResponse);
                
DataTable dt = root.items.ToDataTable<Rootobject.Item>();
```

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;

public static class IListExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
            dataTable.Columns.Add(property.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType);

        if (list == null)
            return dataTable;

        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
                row[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws an exception in ToDataTable<T> method in line `foreach (T item in list)' ** System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**

Comment: Look like the `list` is `null`, check whether it is `null` and prevent it from executing `foreach` loop if it is `null`. Check my latest change for the answer.

Comment: Its actually returning me an empty list. Not sure why. Do you have any code which takes an json response from a dummy rest api and displays the data in a table format?

Comment: Checked this [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LgBodf). I used your provided API URL and it works. You need to check whether the API returns the response and is it matched to your model class before converting to DataTable.

Comment: Is there any replacement for `FiddleHelper.WriteTable(dt);` to display ta data?

Comment: Hi, you may have a read: [Print Contents Of A DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15547959/8017690)

Comment: I am not able to display the table data. I am using a console application. I tried printing the data using foreach loop but the output console keeps closing after displaying for a millisecond.

Comment: Add `Console.ReadLine()` in the end. This will prevent the program exit until you press any key.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the earlier answer, I think this will solve your issue:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using(HttpClient client = new())
    {
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://crmscf.vidyasystems.com/api/gen/items.php");
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response);
        var items = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject["items"]);
        DataTable tester = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(items, (typeof(DataTable)));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
}
```

Comment: I am able to get a response till `JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);`. After that I am getting null for iteams and dt

Comment: Here is the console application created for converting the response to a datatable:

https://github.com/Hawre1987/DotNetDataTableFromJson.git

Comment: This takes a json response from a file, but I am working with response taken from url of an api.

Comment: @SDS, I've updated the answer to get the json from your API endpoint instead of a file, chech it please.

Comment: change this:  
    JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);  
to this:  
    JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response);**

Comment: How do i display the the data in gridview? Can u share a code snippet

Comment: I think this should answer your last question, however I did not test it myself:  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028006/populate-gridview-from-data-table